# Simulating a directory tree platform-independently

Tags: ruby, windows, qt, unix, qfilesystemmodel

I am using Qt and Ruby in an application where I have to manipulate some directories and rename/move files. However, prior to the actual manipulation I need to show a "preview", ie, simulation of the changes. What I've done on OS X and Linux is a collection of `mkdir` and `touch` commands, in a writable tmp space, to build my said "directory tree", fed that to Qt's `QFileSystemModel` widget and `QTreeView`, and I'd get my expected results.

However, I can not do that on Windows, because I have found no native counterpart to `touch` and thus I could not show the files. One suggestion that came to mind is to create my directory tree in memory, but then I can not feed it to `QFileSystemModel` anymore.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows comes with a tool called fsutil, which can be used to create dummy files similar to Unix touch command:

**fsutil file createnew** *PathName length*

I am not sure if fsutil exist per default on the Home editions of Windows, but at least it is in the professional versions of XP through Windows 7.

See the [full documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx?mfr=true) for fsutil.

Comment: Reading the documentation, it indeed looks like a solution to my issue, however, there's a limitation that renders it futile: "You must be logged on as an administrator or a member of the Administrators group in order to use fsutil." Within the context of my application, that does not work for me. Thank you